# Spring Boot - Java FAT Jar - NoClassFoundError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, noclassdeffounderror

In my Java project, I'm having a hard time accessing one of my API's. This API is reached through an external JAR. With a regular run of Spring Boot, I am able to access the API and get some data back, but when I run from a JAR, I get NoClassFoundError. To resolve this issue, I used Maven's shade plugin to create a FAT jar, that will bundle up all my external depenencies, which it has done, but running the program from the shaded jar, I experience the same issue.

Below is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.edm</groupId>
    <artifactId>EDMProd</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>EDMProd</name>
    <description>EDM API Service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Mentor Dependencies -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mentor.datafusion.oi</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.mentor.datafusion.oi</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>     
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dfo</groupId>
            <artifactId>dfo</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dfutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>dfutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mentor.datafusion.dfo.is3</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.mentor.datafusion.dfo.is3</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mentor.is3.edm.login.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.mentor.is3.edm.login.api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>apache-logging-log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-logging-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>       
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mentor.datafusion.dfo.is3.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.mentor.datafusion.dfo.is3.api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mentor.datafusion.dfo.is3.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.mentor.datafusion.dfo.is3.common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>DFTunnelClient</groupId>
            <artifactId>DFTunnelClient</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>is3-server-api</groupId>
            <artifactId>is3-server-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mentor.is3.server.dms.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.mentor.is3.server.dms.api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <finalName>EDM Library Web Service</finalName>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
              <id>shade-my-jar</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                      <mainClass>com.edm.EdmProdApplication</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                  </transformers>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

After launching the shaded jar, here is the exception I get thrown.

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)

May 10, 2021 9:26:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
May 10, 2021 9:26:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.45]
May 10, 2021 9:26:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
May 10, 2021 9:26:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.mentor.datafusion.utils.resources.MGResourceBundle).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
May 10, 2021 9:26:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mentor/is3/client/login/Login] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mentor.is3.client.login.Login
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at com.mentor.datafusion.dfo.is3.login.IS3LoginUtil.performBatchLoginToIS3Server(IS3LoginUtil.java:232)
        at com.mentor.datafusion.dfo.is3.login.IS3BatchAuthenticate.loginImpl(IS3BatchAuthenticate.java:64)
        at com.mentor.datafusion.dfo.login.BatchAuthenticateImpl.login(BatchAuthenticateImpl.java:100)
        at com.mentor.datafusion.dfo.login.BatchAuthenticate.login(BatchAuthenticate.java:51)
        at com.mentor.datafusion.oi.internal.login.AuthenticateWrapper.login(AuthenticateWrapper.java:24)
        at com.intel.Connect.ConnectToEDM(Connect.java:59)
        at com.intel.IntelProd.getAllComponents(IntelProd.java:21)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I've been at this problem for too long now and I'm just not sure what to do. I feel like I've tried everything I've seen on Stack Overflow.

Below is also the source code that is ran when I try to connect to the API

```
package com.edm;

import com.mentor.datafusion.oi.OIObjectManager;
import com.mentor.datafusion.oi.OIObjectManagerFactory;
import com.mentor.datafusion.oi.login.OIAuthenticate;
import com.mentor.datafusion.oi.login.OIAuthenticateFactory;
import com.mentor.datafusion.oi.login.OILoginData;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Connect {

    static OIObjectManagerFactory omf;
    static OIObjectManager om;
    static String SERVER_URL;
    static String SERVER_USERNAME;
    static String SERVER_PASSWORD;
    static String PRODUCTION_LIBRARY;
    static String OSAT_LIBRARY;
    static String CAPACITOR_CLASS;
    static String RESISTOR_CLASS;
    static String INDUCTOR_CLASS;

    public Connect() throws IOException {
        // Read Configuration File
        String currentDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        Path configurationFile_path= Paths.get(currentDirectory).getParent();
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(configurationFile_path + "/src/main/resources/configuration.properties");
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(inputStream);

        // Initialize Server Variables
        this.CAPACITOR_CLASS = prop.getProperty("CAPACITOR_CLASS");
        this.RESISTOR_CLASS = prop.getProperty("RESISTOR_CLASS");
        this.INDUCTOR_CLASS = prop.getProperty("INDUCTOR_CLASS");
        this.PRODUCTION_LIBRARY = prop.getProperty("PRODUCTION_LIBRARY");
        this.SERVER_URL = prop.getProperty("SERVER_URL");
        this.OSAT_LIBRARY = prop.getProperty("OSAT_LIBRARY");
        this.SERVER_USERNAME = prop.getProperty("SERVER_USERNAME");
        this.SERVER_PASSWORD = prop.getProperty("SERVER_PASSWORD");
    }

    public static void ConnectToEDM(String libraryName) {

        try {
            OILoginData loginData = OIAuthenticateFactory.createLoginData("myLoginConfig");
            loginData.setServer(SERVER_URL);
            loginData.setUsername(SERVER_USERNAME);
            loginData.setPassword(SERVER_PASSWORD);
            loginData.setProdLib(PRODUCTION_LIBRARY);
            String applicationName = "Component Library";

            OIAuthenticate auth = OIAuthenticateFactory.createBatchAuthenticate(loginData);
            omf = auth.login(applicationName);
            
            System.out.println("Connected to library: " + libraryName);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Connection failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            om = omf.createObjectManager();
            om.setLibraryConfiguration(libraryName);
            System.out.println("Successfully connected to " + libraryName + " EDM Library.");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the true issue at hand here is, I only need 4 external dependencies to run my API. Locally it is okay, but when I package into JAR, I believe those dependencies rely on other dependencies, so when ran locally, I believe my system knows where to go to get those dependencies, but when packaged into a jar, can't find those dependencies.

As a side note: The way I import dependencies into my project is

1. Add the external jar in the classpath (Eclipse)
2. Include the jar I imported, as a dependency in my pom.xml

I'm new to this, so I'm unsure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: You should spring-boot-maven-plugin and NOT maven-shade-plugin...

Comment: Is there a reason why?

Answer (score 0):

Have looks like you're trying to access the artifacts from a specific repo which requires authentication ??

Check your settings.xml in the .m2 folder , use profile for the repository you're trying to connect .

Let me know your thoughts !

Comment: I don't see a settings.xml file in my .m2 folder.